# How to solve Lyapunov equation via Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Let's say that I have my Lyapunov equation for finding the controllbility gramian  $P$.

The equation is:
$$APA^T - P + BB^T = 0$$

The matrecies  $A, B $ are known.

**Question:**

Can I use the command fzero or fsolve to find $P $ ?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dlyap.html

Comment: Thanks. But I want to learn how to use the built in functions  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $P$ only appears linearly in the equation you can solve it as a system of linear equations. But Matlab and Octave are only good at solving this when the unknown is in vector form. By reshaping $P$, and eventually the rest of the equation as well, by stacking each column of $P$ on top of each other it is possible to transform the initial equation into a form that is easily solvable by Octave and Matlab.

So if the elements of the matrix $P$ can be defined as

$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & \cdots & p_{1n} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & \cdots & p_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_{n1} & p_{n2} & \cdots & p_{nn}
\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}
$$

then the vector form of $P$ will defined as

$$
\vec{p} = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{21} & \cdots & p_{n1} & p_{12} & p_{22} & \cdots & p_{n2} & \cdots \cdots & p_{1n} & p_{2n} & \cdots & p_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}^\top. \tag{2}
$$

When starting with a matrix product $X\,P$ or $P\,Y$, with all matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, then their results can also be converted into a vector. The vector form of the product can also be expressed as $\tilde{X}\,\vec{p}$ and $\tilde{Y}\,\vec{p}$ respectively. It can be shown that $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are both in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2 \times n^2}$ and can be expressed as follows

$$
\tilde{X} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
X & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & X & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & X
\end{bmatrix} \tag{3}
$$

$$
\tilde{Y} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{11}\,I & y_{21}\,I & \cdots & y_{n1}\,I \\
y_{12}\,I & y_{22}\,I & \cdots & y_{n2}\,I \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
y_{1n}\,I & y_{2n}\,I & \cdots & y_{nn}\,I
\end{bmatrix} \tag{4}
$$

where $0$ and $I$ are the zero- and identity-matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. In the case of $X\,P\,Y$ it can be shown that it is equivalent to $\tilde{X}\,\tilde{Y}\,\vec{p}$ or $\tilde{Y}\,\tilde{X}\,\vec{p}$, since $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ commute.

In the case of the discrete Lyapunov equation, which is the slightly more general case of your infinite time controllability Gramian

$$
A\,P\,A^\top - P + Q = 0 \tag{5}
$$

the matrices $X$ and $Y$ are the each others transpose. Using this property then $\tilde{X}\,\tilde{Y}$ can also be written as follows

$$
\tilde{A}\,\tilde{A^\top} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\,A & a_{12}\,A & \cdots & a_{1n}\,A \\
a_{21}\,A & a_{22}\,A & \cdots & a_{2n}\,A \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1}\,A & a_{n2}\,A & \cdots & a_{nn}\,A
\end{bmatrix} \tag{6}
$$

Therefore the discrete Lyapunov equation from $(5)$ can also be written as

$$
\left(\tilde{A}\,\tilde{A^\top} - I_{n^2 \times n^2}\right)\,\vec{p} = - \vec{q} \tag{7}
$$

where $\vec{q}$ is derived from $Q$ in the same way as $\vec{p}$ in $(2)$ from $(1)$. The solution to this equation is simply

$$
\vec{p} = -\left(\tilde{A}\,\tilde{A^\top} - I_{n^2 \times n^2}\right)^{-1}\,\vec{q} \tag{8}
$$

In order to obtain $P$ you just have to reshape $\vec{p}$ into a square matrix again. One example of an implementation of this might look like:

```
function P = discrete_lyapunov_equation(A, Q)
% This function solves A * P * A' - P + Q = 0

n = length(A);
M = zeros(n^2);
for k = 1 : n
    for l = 1 : n
        M((1:n)+n*(k-1),(1:n)+n*(l-1)) = A * A(k,l);
    end
end
P = reshape(-(M - eye(n^2)) \ Q(:), n, n);

end
```

When comparing this against the Matlab function `dlyap()` it usually achieves the same accuracy or sometimes a little better for small $n$ (the accuracy is measured my taking the 2-norm of the left hand side of $(5)$ using the $P$ value obtained from each function). However my function is slower to calculate when $n$ is big. Namely my function is around 5 times slower when $n = 10$, but is around 17 times slower when $n = 20$. For more details look at the first figure below. Above $n = 10$ Matlab sometimes also complains when running my function that the matrix `M` is close the singular. However when comparing the accuracy of my function to that of `dlyap()` then mine is much better above $n = 13$ as can be seen in the second figure below. I think I would prefer accuracy over computation time, especially if you do not have any control over how accurate the result is going to be.

[image: accuracy comparison]

[image: computation time comparison]

When looking into the description of [`dlyap()`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dlyap.html) I looked up one of the references, which mentions the use of Bartel-Stewart's algorithm, which is also mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation#Numerical_solutions) which states: *"...which consists of transforming A and B into Schur form by a QR algorithm, and then solving the resulting triangular system via back-substitution. This algorithm, whose computational cost is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ arithmetical operations"*. So that might also be a place to look into if you would like to know how Matlab potentially does it. However this would go way to deep into numerical methods for the scope of this question, so I will leave it as this. Also this method might give results which have really poor accuracy at large $n$.

Comment: Very good answer. So QR algorithm will solve this problem too ? Octave and MATLAB have QR function implemented.

Comment: +1 For the very detailed answer. I think there is a problem with the MATLAB function. An error of $10^{10}$ suggests that the solution does not converge, or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: @MrYouMath I would think so as well. I also posted a [question regarding this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/362571) on the MATLAB forums.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson The QR algorithm can be used to find the Schur decomposition of a matrix (upper triangular matrix). Using this then it can be shown that this would indeed turn the solving for $\vec{p}$ into a back substitution problem.

Comment: I through I have been used fzero to compute matrix equations. But I might am wrong. So I need to 1. Use QR algorithm to find the schur decomposition. Then I can solve the equation using Ax=b formula?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I also tried to implement this with the Schur decomposition. The computation time did go down a little, however the accuracy for large $n$ got worse than that of dlyap. I also tried a similar implementation for lyap (the continuous Lyapunov equation solver) and got similar result, so more computation time for large $n$, but better accuracy.

Comment: Is there any built in functions to use for solve these matrix equations ?

Comment: Hi Kwin! I'm going to implement your algorithm in C code. I have a control theory library for embedded systems with main focus on control engineering. Let me know if you need to have some kind of matrix algebra C-code and I can rewrite your MATLAB code to C. I have QR, LU, SVD, Chol, Gaussian elimination, inv, etc.

Comment: What do you prefer her? Solving this with LUP-decomposition or QR-decomposition?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Sorry for the late reply. It has been awhile since I looked at this and I won't say I have any preference. I would just say try both and test which is faster/satisfies your accuracy requirement. Also I believe the $A$ matrices I used for the plots in my answer might have been not well conditioned (I used a controllable canonical form). So also keep this in mind when testing for accuracy.

Comment: I used LU factorization because A is square matrix. QR is better choice if A is non-square.