# Prove that a skew symmetric matrix has at least one eigenvalue that $||\lambda_{\text{max}}||_2 > 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, skew-symmetric-matrices

> Assume that we have a skew symmetric matrix $A^T = -A$ and we want to
>   prove that this matrix $A$ has at least one eigenvalue
>   $||\lambda_{\text{max}}||_2 > 1$.

I have tried power iteration method, but this method is not for skew symmatric matrices. So are there any more solutions to this scenario? I'm not after the value of the eigenvalues, only if $A$ has or not has an eigenvalue in the complex plane, that have it's absolute value larger than 1.

Here is an example for $A$ that $||\lambda_{\text{max}}||_2 < 1$

```
 9.8039e-01  -4.2874e-02  -2.4908e-09  -2.3673e-09   2.6530e-10
 4.2874e-02   8.6717e-01  -1.9962e-08  -1.8425e-08   2.5793e-09
 2.5173e-09  -1.9686e-08  -3.5991e-01   9.1056e-01   1.1030e-01
-2.3528e-09   1.8762e-08  -9.0932e-01  -2.9356e-01  -1.6677e-01
 3.7222e-10  -3.1053e-09  -1.1452e-01  -1.6620e-01  -3.9396e-01
```

Here is an example for $A$ that $||\lambda_{\text{max}}||_2 > 1$

```
 1.0012937  -0.0137552   0.0029529  -0.0059114  -0.0028649
 0.0137552   1.0039890  -0.0283006   0.0058254   0.0122123
 0.0029529   0.0283006   1.0053577  -0.0455448  -0.0076796
 0.0059114   0.0058254   0.0455448   1.0046041   0.0641186
-0.0028649  -0.0122123  -0.0076796  -0.0641186   1.0022143
```

Comment: I don't think this is true. Take $$A = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & -a \\ a & \hphantom{-}0  \end{matrix}\right)$$ for $\lvert a\rvert < 1$.

Comment: Yes! But how can I prove it? I want to, by my self, make sure that $A$ has not an eigenvalue that are > 1

Comment: What do you mean prove it? I'm disproving your statement by using a counterexample. You say you are trying to prove that if $A$ is skew-symmetric, then $A$ has an eigenvalue of absolute value larger than $1$. I have given you an example of $A$ which is skew-symmetric and does not have an eigenvalue of absolute value larger than $1$. This refutes the claim, and thus you can conclude that the implication is false.

Comment: @User8128 No, I'm talking about to prove that if or not, $A$ has $||\lambda_{max}|| > 1$$

Comment: If you are worried about actually computing the eigenvalues of $A$, you can do that by the usual method: find the values $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $\text{det}(A-\lambda I) = 0$. In this case, $\text{det}(A-\lambda I) = \lambda^2 + a^2$.

Comment: @User8128 I don't do math by hand ;) GNU Octave. hehe

Comment: I'm a bit unclear what you are actually asking. If you have a specific matrix and you just want to find the eigenvalues, I am certain Octave has a built in function to do so. In MATLAB, $\lambda = \text{eig}(A)$ will compute the eigenvalues for you, the output will be the vector of $n$ eigenvalues when $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. I'm betting it's the same in Octave (though I'm not sure).

Comment: @User8128 Yes, I know that I can find the eigenvalues from Octave, but I'm talking about the practival method how to do. Not the function from Octave.

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't have an easy algorithm off the top of my head. However, in this case, a necessary condition to have an eigenvalue with $\lvert \lambda \rvert > 1$ is that you will need a row whose absolute sum is larger than $1$ (Gershgorin circle theorem).

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Use the power iteration method on $-A^2$, which is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix; that should work well enough.  $-A^2$ has an eigenvalue with magnitude at least $1$ iff this holds for $A$.

Comment: @User8128 So if I loop throu all rows in $A$ and them sum them and take the sum to the absolute. Then I can determine if $A$ has an absolute eigenvalue larger than 1?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You think that? Hmm, it could be worth to try. You sure that I can determine if the $A$ has en absolute eigenvalue larger than 1?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: @User8128 I think your solution works! Can you post an answer? I have updated my question.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson in theory yes, but for pathological cases the method might take a long time to converge.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What do you think about what User8128 said about Gershgorin circle theorem ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I suspect that it will generally fail to definitively tell you whether you have such an eigenvalue

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you sure about that?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson no, that's why I said "I suspect that" rather than "I'm sure that"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So if power method will only work in theory for $-A^2$, then it's not work to try it.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I thought you were asking me about the Gershgorin method.  Regarding the power method: I am sure that the power method will converge (in the sense that $\|Av_k\|/\|v_k\|$ converges, even if $v_k$ doesn't).  What I am not sure about is how many iterations it will take to converge to a satisfactory degree.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Also I have no idea what you mean by the phrase "it's not work to try it"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I tried to use Octave's `eig` on $-A^2$ and I did get eigenvalues larger than 1.  But if I only try $eig(A)$, then I don't get eigenvalues larger than 1.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Well, you said above "in theory yes, but for pathological cases the method might take a long time to converge". I interprent that as power method is not a secure method.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson It seems like you meant to say "it's not worth trying", then.  About the octave stuff: keep in mind that eig(A) should get you imaginary eigenvalues.  If $A$ is skew-symmetric, the maximum eigenvalue of $-A^2$ is equal to the square of the maximum magnitude among the eigenvalues of $A$.  If $A$ is not **exactly** skew symmetric (up to numerical precision), then this doesn't work.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Are my matricies above skew symmetric?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson they are not.  For a skew-symmetric matrix, the diagonal entries must be zero.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Okey, my bad. Hmm, what shape are them in? skew Symmetric with random diagonal?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I guess so, and unfortunately that's not a structure that you can really take advantage of.  If the diagonal entries are approximately equal (as in your second example), then you should be able to use gradient descent on $A^TA$ since the maximum singular value will be approximately equal to the maximum eigenvalue-magnitude.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Isin't that better if I take SVD on $A$ and check it largest singular value? Do you think I can use determinant? I have heard from some one at my university that if the determinant is larger than 1, the absolute eigenvalues is larger than 1.

Comment: @Daniel It is true that if the determinant is larger than $1$, then there had to be an eigenvalue that was larger than $1$.  However, the reverse does not hold: we could have an eigenvalue larger than $1$ and a determinant less than $1$.

Comment: @Daniel You could take an SVD and check the largest singular value, but I'm not sure why that would be so much of an improvement over computing the eigenvalues and looking for the largest one.  The point of the power method that I was suggesting was to find the largest singular value without computing the others.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Okey. Thanks for the information. Perhaps I should try gradient descent to solve....det(A-sI) = 0 ?

Comment: @Daniel as soon as you do anything involving $\det(A - sI)$, you're better off just computing the eigenvalues with a built-in method

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Pardon?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom perhaps I should go with Lyapunov stability? If the Lyapunov equation is not stable, then the eigenvalues are over 1.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom For example: $MA + A^TM = -I$ Where $M$ is a unique positive definite matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix. If $M$ is not positive definite, then $A$ has eigenvalues larger than 1.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hi again! This is the solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483215/how-to-solve-lyapunov-equation-via-matlab-octave Solve with Lyapunov theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Take for instance $A = 0$.

Comment: Okej. That's a prof. But assume that we have a skew symmetric matrix and I claim that this matrix $A$ has no eignevalues larger than 1. Can you prove that my matrix as it?

Comment: I'm not asking for a theoretical proof. I'm talking about a computational proof. You have a skew symmetric matrix $A$ and you want to test it if it has an eigenvalue larger than $||\lambda_{max}|| > 1$.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson as it's currently written, it sounds like you're trying to prove that every skew symmetric matrix has at least one eigenvalue greater than $1$.  However, with this discussion it appears that you have a **specific** skew symmetric matrix $A$, you know that $A$ has an eigenvalue larger than $1$, and you would like to "prove" that it has an eigenvalue larger than $1$.  Is this what you were trying to ask about?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I could imagine that OP means: He has given a matrix and he wants a (more or less) quick test in order to check whether there is such an eigenvalue (without calculating the eigenvalues).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes and no. I have a specific $A$ skew symmetric matrix and I want to **test** it if that matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue larger than 1. Notice that these eigenvalues are on the complex plane. But I'm happy just to see if the absolute value is larger than 1 or not.

Comment: @Jan Yes. A quick simple test. Not intressted in any value. Just boolean answer.

Comment: Updated my question