# Efficient solution to this matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, sylvester-equation

I am trying to find the solution to $X_1$ and $X_2 \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, which satisfies the following matrix equation:

$$A_1 X_1 + X_1 A_1^\dagger + A_2 X_2 + X_2 A_2^\dagger = C_1 $$
$$B_1 X_1 + X_1 B_1^\dagger + B_2 X_2 + X_2 B_2^\dagger = C_2 $$

where $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2, C_1, C_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are symmetric positive definite matrices.

From the first equation, notice that if we have $A_2 = 0$, we have a Lyapunov equation to which the question is addressed. More generally, when $A_2 \neq 0$, we have a simultaneous equation of "2D Lyapunov equation". Can I recast this problem into a normal Lyapunov or Sylvester-type equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see an obvious way one could recast your problem into a Sylvester equation. However, you can still write your problem as a system of linear equation using a technique which can be used to also solve a Sylvester equation. Namely, by using [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). Using this your two equation can also be written as

\begin{align}
(I \otimes A_1 + A_1 \otimes I)\,\text{vec}(X_1) + (I \otimes A_2 + A_2 \otimes I)\,\text{vec}(X_2) &= \text{vec}(C_1), \\
(I \otimes B_1 + B_1 \otimes I)\,\text{vec}(X_1) + (I \otimes B_2 + B_2 \otimes I)\,\text{vec}(X_2) &= \text{vec}(C_2), \\
\end{align}

with $I$ the $n \times n$ identity matrix. This can also be combined into the following system of linear equations

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I \otimes A_1 + A_1 \otimes I & I \otimes A_2 + A_2 \otimes I \\
I \otimes B_1 + B_1 \otimes I & I \otimes B_2 + B_2 \otimes I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{vec}(X_1) \\ \text{vec}(X_2)
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{vec}(C_1) \\ \text{vec}(C_2)
\end{bmatrix},
$$

which can be solved using any system of linear equations solver.

Comment: I did notice this. I was initially motivated to reduce the complexity of the numerical solvers involved. This pursuit is no longer necessary since a general linear equations solver is better or equal to the complexity involved in numerical methods for Lyapunov equations.

Comment: @Sid it can be noted that solving it this way might take longer than if it could be formulated as a Sylvester equation and use a solver for that, as is [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2483731/76466).